# Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'IProductRepository' could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, repository

> Error: Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'IEnumerable<product> is less accessible than property 'IProductRepository.Products'

```
namespace SportsStore.Domain.Abstract
{
    public interface IProductRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; }            
    }
}
```

I don't understand what the error message means; can someone please help me determine what's wrong?

Comment: Your code is not properly marked, so it is really hard to se.

Comment: Your code is not complete, but I bet that your `Product` class is `internal`. You, obviously, cannot use an `internal` class inside any `public` type (as the compiler says).

Comment: It means you're exposing a type to a scope that does not have access to the type.

Comment: In the class where you are implementing `IProductRepository` interface you must have `Products` property as public.

Answer (score 0):

If you have any of these class definitions:

```
class Product // defaults to internal
```

or

```
internal class Product
```

Then the `Product` type is not visible outside of the assembly. There's a conflict if you define this interface:

```
public interface IProductRepository
{
    IEnumerable<Product> Products { get; }            
}
```

This says that the interface is `public`, visible from outside the assembly. But that's not possible because it contains a type - `Product` - which is *not* visible outside the assembly. It's like a store that sells products that no customer is allowed to know about. It can't make sense.

There's no way to reconcile that inconsistency, so the compiler won't build it.

You can make them both `internal` or both `public`. You can make the interface `internal` and `Product` `public`. But you can't make the interface `public` and `Product` `internal` because of the conflict it creates.